# dispatching touch events from overlay view to background

Tags: android, overlay, touch-event, dispatch

I have the following service to display an overlay view over every app in the system and getting the touch events. Because of the TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT the touches can't go through to the background so it's useless. I thought that I could obtaing a MotionEvent and dispatch it to the background view using the same x,y that I just detected.

**QUESTION: How do I define the background view to which I will send the event?. Given that I can detect at all times what the foreground application is, can I define a view of that window so that i can dispatch the event?

```
public class OverlayService extends Service {

    LinearLayout oView;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        oView = new LinearLayout(this);   
        oView.setBackgroundColor(0x88ff0000); // The translucent red color
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                0 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);        
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.addView(oView, params);

        oView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @SuppressLint("Recycle")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    int x = (int) event.getX();
                    int y = (int) event.getY();
                    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
                    // List of meta states found here: developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
                    int metaState = 0;
                    MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                        downTime, 
                        eventTime, 
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 
                        x, 
                        y, 
                        metaState
                    );
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Integer.toString(x)+"    "+Integer.toString(y), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Dispatch touch event to background
                    //              ?
                    //              ?
                    // Dispatch touch event to background



                }
                // Obtain MotionEvent object

                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {            
        super.onDestroy();
        if(oView!=null){
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            wm.removeView(oView);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: fortunatelly its not possible

Comment: it is possible. GMD Gesture Control does it. as for the fortunatelly comment: not everyone has bad intentions.

Comment: unfortunately no...GMD does it using root access. Without root access i don't think it can be done

Comment: How to do it if I with root access?